# Rectangle thickness java

Tags: java, shapes, rectangles, outline

I need to outline in blue 1 rectangle at a time when selected. The code works but I cant see the blue outline very well. what is the easiest way to make the outline thicker. Wither that be drawing another shape over it or something else.

```
private void displayBlock(Graphics g)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {

        if (occupant[i].equals("Empty"))
        {
            //Sets the rectangle red to show the room is occupied
            g.setColor(emptyColor);
            g.fillRect(150+(i*50), 120, aptWidth, aptHeight);

        }
        else
        {
            //Sets the rectangle green to show the room is free
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(150+(i*50), 120, aptWidth, aptHeight);               
        }
        if (i == selectedApartment)
        {

            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.drawRect(150+(i*50), 120, aptWidth, aptHeight);

        }
        else
        {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(150+(i*50), 120, aptWidth, aptHeight);
        }

        // Draws the numbers in the Corresponding boxes
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString(Integer.toString(i+1), 150+(i*50)+15, 120+25);
    }

    //Drawing the key allowing the user to see what the colours refer to
    g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    g.drawString("Key", 20,120);
    g.drawString("Occupied",60,150);
    g.drawString("Empty", 60, 170);

    // Drawing the boxes to show what the colours mean in the key             
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(20, 130, 25, 25);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(20, 130, 25, 25);
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(20,150,25,25);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(20,150,25,25);

} // End of displayBlock
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the thickness of the rectangle by creating a `Graphics2D` object and setting its [stroke](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BasicStroke.html).

```
java.awt.Graphics2D g2 = (java.awt.Graphics2D) g.create();
g2.setStroke(new java.awt.BasicStroke(3)); // thickness of 3.0f
g2.setColor(Color.blue);
g2.drawRect(10,10,50,100); // for example
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could draw a second rectangle immediately inside the first one.  Or multiple of them.

```
public static void drawRectangle(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height, int thickness) {
    g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
    if (thickness > 1) {
        drawRectangle(g, x + 1, y + 1, width - 2. height - 2, thickness - 1);
    }
}
```